# Anchor # not working in Chrome and Opera(FF works)

Tags: wordpress, hyperlink, menu, anchor, scrollto

Have strange issue with website, and i am strongly convinced it worked before. (Do not know if it started to happen after WP update)
Have one page website with linking within homepage (#section1, #section2), and menu is linked to sections.
Suddenly, i realized in Chrome and Opera, menu clicking leads nowhere.
Firefox working perfectly, IE, Safari too.
No JS errors in console, can't find an issue.
Anybody can help me?

[Link for site](http://leadwebtech.com/)

Comment: Hi Lanchushki! Where did this scroll functionality come from? Is this your own code or are you using a plugin or did it come as part of a theme? If you can find the code that's meant to be doing it then it will be easier to debug.

Comment: Don't know why or you fixed it but my Chrome 62 works well.

Comment: Still not working :/

Answer (score 2):

You can try to fix the broken anchor links in your wordpress website like this:

1. Go to https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo and get these 2 files: jquery.scrollTo.js and jquery.scrollTo.min.js
2. Go to your website's file system and find the subfolder: /wp-content/themes/YOUR_THEME/js/libs   OR   /wp-content/themes/YOUR_THEME/javascripts OR just search in your wordpress website's filesystem for these 2 files:jquery.scrollTo.min.js & jquery.scrollTo.minf915.js and remove them.
3. Copy in that folder the 2 files of step 1.

Credits to Mike Some and Andrei Sergheev for finding the solution.

Answer (score -2):

This works:

Instead of using this:

/#your-anchor

or this:

http://yoururl.com/#your-anchor

You have to use this:

**http://yoururl.com/index.php/#your-anchor**

with the *index.php* in the url

Comment: Why on earth would adding index.php in the URL solve this??